# Allowing TextBox.Text to accept different types

Tags: c#, vb.net, textbox

I am translating a VB program to C#. The VB program has a WinForm control and in the settings portion, the following code is used,

```
Me.xXXTextBox.Text = Me._settings.XXX
```

The only thing is that the RHS of the above is not a string but,

```
Public Property XXX() As Single
    Get
        Return Me._xXX
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Single)
        If value <> Me._xXX Then
            Me._xXX = value
            Me._dirty = True
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

How do I do the above in C# please? I have translated the code into C# but I cannot get
past the type "mis-match".

Just for more background, in the VB program, the `TextBox` is implemented as a `NumericTextBox` which inherits from `TextBox`. I have implemented this in C# too but still no go.

I am missing something but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: `_settings.XXX.ToString()`?

Comment: have you tried some free [code conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) ?

Comment: Ah...the joys of not using `Option Strict On` in VB.NET.

Comment: Huh?  Everything derives from `System.Object`, which has `ToString()`.....

Comment: Yep sorry scratch that comment.  The thing is that in VB, there is no need for ToString().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the `single` to a `string`. C# is not that easy on explicit type casting as VB.NET (you should be happy about that):

```
this.xXXTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(this._settings.XXX)
```

Or

```
this.xXXTextBox.Text = this._settings.XXX.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

VB often allows implicit conversions that c# will not allow, therefor in the first glance I would recommend using `_settings.XXX.ToString()`.

However, after reading the last paragraph in your question, I'm not so sure. You need to check the VB source to see if the `NumericTextBox.Text` should be of type `String` or `Single`. If it's a single, you need to implement the same in your c# translation. If it's a string, you need to use the `ToString` method.

Comment: The NumericTextBox inherits from TextBox and only overrides the OnKeyPress event to restrict input to numerals and related only.  Aside from that there are 3 new properties IntValue and DecimalValue which return the respective types (Int32 or Decimal) from Text and which are readonly and an AllowSpace property (R/W).

Comment: in that case, use an explicit conversion (i.e ToString).